# WebTestClient gets 404 on Spring Boot 2.4.0-M3 while works fine on 2.4.0-M2

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have test that works properly with Spring 2.4.0-M2 but after upgrading to 2.4.0-M3 it breaks - returns 404 for a route that is registered.

My app:

```
@SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class ExampleApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ExampleApp>(
        init = {
            addInitializers(BeansInitializer())
        },
        args = args
    )
}
```

beans:

```
class BeansInitializer : ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {
    @Suppress("LongMethod")
    override fun initialize(applicationContext: GenericApplicationContext) {
        beans {
            bean {
                router {
                    "/routes".nest {
                        GET("/{id}") { ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(Foo("ok")) }
                        POST("/") { ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(Foo("ok")) }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            .initialize(applicationContext)
    }
}

data class Foo(val status: String)
```

My test:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = [
        ExampleApp::class
    ]
)
class FailingTest @Autowired constructor(
    context: ApplicationContext,
) {
    val webTestClient: WebTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
        .configureClient()
        .build()

    @Test
    fun `should interact with routes`() {
        webTestClient
            .post()
            .uri("/routes")
            .bodyValue(SampleBody("123"))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk // returns 404 on 2.4.0-M3 / passes on 2.4.0-M2
    }

    data class SampleBody(val id: String)
}
```

test `application.yml`

```
context:
  initializer:
    classes: com.example.BeansInitializer
```

On `2.4.0-M3` tests fail with following message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 NOT_FOUND>
```

On `2.4.0-M2` they pass.

Is there something that changed through the versions? Or this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in behaviour that you are seeing is due to an improvement in Spring Framework during the development of 5.3.

By default, Spring Framework will match an optional trailing path separator (`/`). This optional `/` should be in addition to the path specified in your routes.

You have two routes:

- `GET /routes/{id}`
- `POST /routes/`

The support for an optional trailing path separator means that you could make a get request to `/routes/56/` (an additional trailing `/`), but it should not mean that you can make a request to `POST /routes` (removal of a trailing `/`).

If you want to be able to make `POST` requests to both `/routes` and `/routes/`, you should define the route as `/routes`:

```
beans {
    bean {
        router {
            "/routes".nest {
                GET("/{id}") { ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(Foo("ok")) }
                POST("") { ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(Foo("ok")) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer - is this change documented? I wonder if there were more of such.

Comment: Changes between milestones aren't typically documented to this level of detail as it's to be expected that things will change as a new release is in development. Changes between releases, e.g. from Spring Framework 5.2 to 5.3, are more likely to be documented. You can find information about's what's new and upgrading to new versions on the Spring Framework wiki: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions. Similar information for Spring Boot is also available in its release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki#release-notes.